# Input text in field change background color of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have the div background color change colors only when there is text in the input field and when there is no text there the color doesn't change or it reverts back to the original color. Here is my code so far and it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#inputDatabaseName').change(function () { 
            $(this).parent().find('#colorchange').css('background-color','#ff0000');
            $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="colorchange">
        <input id="inputDatabaseName">
        <table id="searchResults"><tr><td>empty</td></tr></table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Your JS doesn't even appear to be valid. Try jsfiddle.net (jshint)

Comment: Long story short, you closed your change function but not your ready function. Fix that and try again. And in the future, check your error consoles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using classes instead of changing CSS attributes. This should work

```
$(function () {
    $('#inputDatabaseName').keypress(function () { 
        var $this = $(this),
            $div = $(this).parent(); // Cache the jQuery selectors to make code faster
        if ($this.val().length > 0) {
            $div.addClass("hasContent");
        } else {
            $div.removeClass("hasContent");
        }
    });
});
```

Now add some CSS:

```
#colorchange { background-color: white } /* default color */
#colorchange.hasContent { background-color: red } /* updated color */
#colorchange #inputDatabaseName { background-color: white } /* default color */
#colorchange.hasContent #inputDatabaseName { background-color: red } /*updated color*/
```

Comment: you code only changes the color of the input field and not the div that it sits inside of.

Comment: You did not mention updating the input field as well... I'll update in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be targeting the **wrong element**

Your selector is supposed to be

```
$(this).parent('#colorchange')
```

`$(this).parent()` points to `div id="colorchange">`

And you are trying to find again which will search its children

And use `keyup` event instead of the `change` if you want the change to be reflected immediately.

**Also `ID` is supposed to be unique on the page.**

So `$('#colorchange').css(`  should do.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inputDatabaseName').keyup(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $colorDiv = $('#colorchange');
        defaultColor = 'initial';
        // If value is not empty assign a color
        // otherwise this will be set to default.
        if ($this.val() !== '') {
            defaultColor = '#ff0000';
        }
        $('#colorchange').css('background-color', defaultColor);
        $this.css('background-color', defaultColor);
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/WMcTP/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this javascript

```
     $('#inputDatabaseName').change(function () { 
         if($(this).val() ==="") {
             $(this).parents('#colorchange').css('backgroundColor','red');}
         else {
             $(this).parents('#colorchange').css('backgroundColor','green');
         }
     });
```